# Exception when replacing Fragament from within fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-databinding

I have an Activity with a FrameLayout for the fragment.
I add the fragment in the standard way:

```
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ProfileFragmentFirst profileFragmentFirst = new ProfileFragmentFirst();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(ExtrasTags.ARG_PROFILE_OBJECT, profileObject);
    profileFragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, profileFragmentFirst);
    transaction.commit();
```

This works perfectly with no problems.

Within the fragment I have a button which, when clicked, needs to replace the currently active fragment with another. 
It calls a method in the activity to do this:

```
    @Override
public void startFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

When I do that the app fails with the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d00cb (com.digle.android:id/fragment_container) for fragment ProfileBadgesFragment{2239633d #1 id=0x7f0d00cb}
```

So, it claims, it can not find the FrameLayout for the fragment even though I used it earlier! 
A little more searching and I discovered that it is looking inside the Fragment layout for the layout instead of inside the Activity (I proved this by adding a FrameLayout into the fragment layout and lo-and-behold my second fragment appeared there).

However, this code works perfectly elsewhere in my app.

The MAJOR difference between the two cases is that in this case the first fragment uses Data Binding whereas in the case where it works it doesn't.
The buttons I click are bound to an event object.

For example:

```
<Button
..
..
android:onClick="@{clicksListener.onBadgesClick}"
/>
```

With:

```
       public class ClicksListener {
        public void onBadgesClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onBadgesClick");
            ProfileBadgesFragment profileBadgesFragment = new ProfileBadgesFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putSerializable(ExtrasTags.ARG_PROFILE_BADGES, profileObject.userBadgesEntity);
            profileBadgesFragment.setArguments(args);
            startFragment(profileBadgesFragment);
        }
  }
```

And, of course, the binding. The click works perfectly but, as I said earlier, it looks inside the fragment layout instead of the activity layout.

Using build-tools 23.0.3 and everything else is up-to-date.

Comment: `No view found for id 0x7f0d00cb (com.digle.android:id/fragment_container)` Your trying to put your fragment in container that is not available at that instance. Are you replace fragment inside fragment ?

Comment: That's the problem. It is TRYING to do that but I don't want to and it only happens when the first fragment is built using data-binding.

Answer (score 0):

`R.id.fragment_container` is not a part of your fragment. Instead it is a part of your container activity.

If you want to add/replace any fragment from a fragment you should send a callback to your container activity using listener interface and then in your container activity, you should be doing `startFragment()` .

Comment: That's effectively what I am doing with the buttons. The click-listeners are defined within the activity not the fragment.

Comment: Where is onBadgesClick(View view) defined?

Comment: I guess something is missing because you are calling startFragment() with 2 params startFragment(profileBadgesFragment, 1); but startFragment(Fragment fragment)  takes single param. So how are you saying that you are calling startFragment(Fragment fragment) ?

Comment: :) Yeah. I removed the second parameter when I copied the code (for clarity) but forgot to remove it in the call!

Comment: ClicksListener is a public class but you are saying you have onBadgesClick(View view) defined in the activity , how is it possible ?

Comment: I posted short hand. It is a class which I instantiate with that code for the click.

Answer (score 0):

in startFragment instead of getSupportFragmentManager() use getParentFragment().getFragmentManager();

Hope it will help you

Comment: The thing is that the code is run inside the Activity so there is no "getParentFragment()".

Comment: make method in fragment only where button is,remove from activity.

Comment: I tried running from the fragment first but got the same result. I can't use getParentFragment since there is no parent fragment.